# Снятие мута после перезапуска бота discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

представим ситуации: бот перезагрузился, у некоторых пользователей был мут, как сделать так, чтоб после перезапуска бот снимал мут в нужное время, и можно ли это как-то совместить с базой данных sqlite3?
заранее благодарю!

Comment: При выдаче мута, сохранять данные о пользователе и времени, когда его нужно размутить, в отдельный файл (БД, json и т.п.). При включении бота считывать данные из этого файла и ждать указанного времени для каждого пользователя

Comment: это я сделал, но не понимаю как после чтения файла бд, можно сделать снятие мута в нужное время

Comment: Из бд узнаете время, в которое нужно размутить пользователя и в отдельном потоке ждете пока не наступит это время. Если непонятно как это реализовать — переформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на этой проблеме и приведите пример кода, где у вас что-то не получается

Comment: А вообще, нет необходимости придумывать костыли с ролями и запоминанием времени. В дискорде уже давно появилась встроенная функция мута — называется `timeout`. Просто вызываете [*этот метод*](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.timeout) у объекта участника (`discord.Member`), передаете нужные аргументы и все

Comment: спасибо, вы мне помогли:)